# Unable to fetch PDF file from Asset in Flutter, how can I fetch the PDF directly

Tags: pdf, flutter, pdf-viewer

I have attached the code. How can I fetch the PDF from assets? I think calling the init function could solve, but I couldn't call it perfect. I want to fetch the pdf without using any button or else something. 
So, I need to fetch it directly as soon as the Class InformationTechnology call.

```
class InformationTechnology extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InformationTechnologyState createState() => _InformationTechnologyState();
}  

class InformationTechnology extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _InformationTechnologyState createState() => _InformationTechnologyState();
    }

    class _InformationTechnologyState extends State<InformationTechnology> {
      String pdfasset = "assets/IT.pdf";
      PDFDocument _doc;
      bool _loading = false;
      @override
      void initState() { 
        super.initState();

      }
      _initPDF()async{
        setState(() {
          _loading = true;
        });
        final doc = await PDFDocument.fromAsset(pdfasset);
        setState(() {
          _doc = doc;
          _loading = false;
        });
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
           title: Text("Introduction to Information Technology"),
           centerTitle: true,
           backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
          body: _loading?
          Center(
           child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ):PDFViewer(document: _doc), 
          );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try calling the _initPDF method from inside the initState? Because it isn't in there now and doesn't seem to be called anywhere else.

Comment: Graham D I have called now, the PDF has been fetched to slow, can I speed up?

Comment: If the PDF is an asset that exists on your device then that is as fast as it can be. Is it very large? I haven't used PDFDocument so can't comment on it's speed.